# C programming - Unable to read user input immediately

Tags: c, input, range

I am writing a program where the user is required to enter in a number between 2 numbers. A minimum and a maximum. The user must input the number within these parameters in order for the program to run successfully.

This is the function calling getIntFromRange.

```
void test04_getIntFromRange(void)
{
    int intValue;

    printf("TEST #4 - Instructions:\n"
        "1) Enter the number '14' [ENTER]\n"
        ":>");

    // You may want to comment the next line if you have not yet created the getInteger function:
    intValue = getIntFromRange(-40, 14);

    printf("////////////////////////////////////////\n");
    printf("TEST #4 RESULT: ");
    if (intValue == 14)
    {
        printf("*** PASS *** \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("### FAILED ###\n");
    }
    printf("////////////////////////////////////////\n\n");
}
```

This is the code I have written for `getIntFromRange`

```
int getIntFromRange(int lower_bound, int upper_bound)
{
    int value = 0;
    scanf("%d", &value);

    while (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
        printf("Error: Value must be an integer: ");
        scanf("%*s");
        clearStandardInputBuffer();
    }

    while (value > upper_bound || value < lower_bound) {
        printf("ERROR: Value must be between %d and %d inclusive: ", lower_bound, upper_bound);
        scanf("%d", &value);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it does not register immediately when the user inputs 14. I have to press enter multiple times before the code is registered. This is the output of the program before it passes.

```
TEST #4 - Instructions:
1) Enter the number '14' [ENTER]
:>14

14
////////////////////////////////////////
TEST #4 RESULT: *** PASS ***
////////////////////////////////////////

Assignment #1 Milestone #1 completed!
```

Comment: `getIntFromRange` reads a number twice, once at the beginning with no error checking and again in the `while` loop condition. The first is discarded.

Comment: ChecksOverStripes,   Why is `scanf("%*s");` there before `clearStandardInputBuffer();`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first of all. You are reading input twice. Once in the beggining of the function, and second time you're reading it in this chunk of code (in the while loop condition):

```
while (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
    printf("Error: Value must be an integer: ");
    scanf("%*s");
    clearStandardInputBuffer();
}
```

You can delete this line of code:

`scanf("%d", &value);`

Just at the beginning of the function, and that should work just fine. Also, you probably want to use that `clearStandardInputBuffer()` function just after you repeat using scanf() function in the above block of code, so the correct order of those lines of code would be:

```
while (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
    clearStandardInputBuffer();
    printf("Error: Value must be an integer: ");
    scanf("%*s");
}
```

So your `getIntFromRange` function would look like this:

```
int getIntFromRange(int lower_bound, int upper_bound)
{
    int value = 0;

    
    while (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
        clearStandardInputBuffer();
        printf("Error: Value must be an integer: ");
        scanf("%*s");
    }
    while (value > upper_bound || value < lower_bound) {
        printf("ERROR: Value must be between %d and %d inclusive: ", lower_bound, upper_bound);
        scanf("%d", &value);
        
    }
}
```

Even though your `scanf()` function is in the while loop, it will ask you to input anyways. So your function will ask for input just after the initialization of variable `value` and then second time in while loop.

You probably should also consider adding another wrong input handling in the second while loop, like clearing buffer, since your user can enter a wrong input in the second while loop too, like for example, enter `w` character. If your user will do that, you can have an infinite loop.

Also - if your `clearStandardInputBuffer()` function is done correctly, you don't need to use `scanf("%*s")` in the first while loop.

Comment: thank you for your help! The code is working now.